# How can I put objects which i get to array in state?

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I get info about pokemons and now I want to add a list off it to array pokemonList which in state, but I got an error. How can I put pokeData to my pokemonList to map him than?

```
class PokemonList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pokemonList: []
        }
        this.getPokemonList()        
    }

    getPokemonList=()=>{
            fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=12')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((listPokemons) => {
                listPokemons.results.forEach(function(aboutPokemon){
                    let aboutPokemonUrl = aboutPokemon.url;
                    fetch(aboutPokemonUrl)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((pokeData) => {
                        this.setState({
                            pokemonList: pokeData
                        })
                    })
                 })
            })
        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `setState` multiple times within a loop updating the same value. Since react [batches state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), you will need to use a functional update in order for this to work (regardless of the batching, it looks like you're replacing vs adding anyway).

Assuming `pokeData` is an object that you're trying to add to the state array, you could try something like this:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  pokemonList: [...prevState.pokemonList, pokeData]
}))
```

---

You'll also need to change your `forEach` from

```js
forEach(function(aboutPokemon){
```

to

```js
forEach((aboutPokemon) => {
```

Comment: It is doesn't work I hae this error                                                                            `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at eval (PokemonList.js?acb0:26)`

Comment: Updated the answer.